# MvvmCross - UI freezes when I call Task.Run

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

Can anyone educate me why UI freezes during heavy calculation:

```
var ret = await Task.Run(() => this._service.CalcFourier(100000, progress));
```

I have a progress bar that is binding 'Value' property, but bar not updating until calculation finished. When I placed breakpoint to setter method of 'CurrentCalcCount' and start calculation, 'RaisePropertyChanged' has called every time.

How to avoid blocking UI... I've working on it the whole day and I don't know why. Any body can fix the code or have some explain to help me out? Thanks.

CalcView.xaml

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Calculate pi with fourier transform method." Margin="3" />
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Calc time:" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding CalculationCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="150" Margin="3"/>
        <Button Content="Start" Margin="3,0,3,3" Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <ProgressBar MinHeight="25" Margin="5" Maximum="{Binding CalculationCount}" Value="{Binding CurrentCalcCount}" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" MaxWidth="100" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding ProgressText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

'CalcCommand' and other properties are defined as below:

CalcViewModel.cs

```
    private MvxCommand _calcCommand;

    public ICommand CalcCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _calcCommand ??
                   (_calcCommand = new MvxCommand(DoCalcCommand, () => !InProgress));
        }
    }

    private async void DoCalcCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            InProgress = true;

            var progress = new Progress<CalcProgressInfo>(info => Dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(() =>
            {
                CurrentCalcCount = info.CurrentCount;
                ProgressText = info.Message;
            }));

            var ret = await Task.Run(() => this._service.CalcFourier(this._calculationCount, progress));

            ProgressText += Environment.NewLine + ret;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ProgressText = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            InProgress = false;
        }
    }
```

CalcFourier command in Model:

CalcService.cs

```
    private bool _cancel;

    public double CalcFourier(int count, IProgress<CalcProgressInfo> progress)
    {
        var sigma = 0.0;
        var n = 1;

        foreach (
            var i in
                Enumerable.Range(1, count).TakeWhile(_ => !_cancel))
        {
            progress.Report(new CalcProgressInfo(i,
                string.Format("Calculation is in progress now. - {0}/{1}", i, count)));

            sigma += 1.0 / n / n;
            n += 2;
        }

        progress.Report(this._cancel
            ? new CalcProgressInfo(0, "Calculation has canceled.")
            : new CalcProgressInfo(count, "Calculation has completed."));
        _cancel = false;

        return Math.Sqrt(sigma * 8);
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at the [How to call a Visual C# method asynchronously](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582) page on MSDN.

Comment: i think it freezes because you are waiting for this Process because it is part of your `Command` so instead of [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)

you could try the [BackgroundWorker(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I think I got it now. I'll continue learning aout asynchronous pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your processing code is flooding the UI with updates. It doesn't take long at all to perform a couple double-precision divisions and an integer addition; just the construction of your progress report string will almost certainly take longer than that.

Instead of:

```
progress.Report(new CalcProgressInfo(i,
    string.Format("Calculation is in progress now. - {0}/{1}", i, count)));
```

Consider trying this:

```
if (i % 100 == 0)
{
    progress.Report(new CalcProgressInfo(i,
        string.Format("Calculation is in progress now. - {0}/{1}", i, count)));
}
```

And playing with higher/lower values to replace the `100` until you can see your updates at a reasonable pace (readable but not too slow).

The reason that you don't see any updates at all is due to a prioritization of the UI message loop; "code" messages such as "update this progress value" have a higher priority than "paint" messages. So if the loop is flooded with update messages, it never gets around to repainting the UI.

P.S. There's no need to use `Dispatcher`; `Progress<T>` will marshal to the appropriate thread by default:

```
var progress = new Progress<CalcProgressInfo>(info =>
{
    CurrentCalcCount = info.CurrentCount;
    ProgressText = info.Message;
});
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the detailed explanation. I didn't understand about UI message loop.
I'll consider about priority of messages from now on. Thanks a lot again.